# Thanks before/Thanks in advance?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm native to a country where the expression **"thanks before"** is widely used. Is it grammatically correct?

Does **"thanks in advance"** really sound rude to (some) native English speakers?

Can you suggest other expressions to be used as alternatives?

Is there anything (grammatically) wrong with the way I write my questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt *thanks before* is commonly used in this sense. *Thanks in advance* is frequently used. Here is some data on the matter. If we let Google expand our search for context, notice that *thanks in advance* has the context we want.
[image]

If it is written, then I personally don't think it is rude, since I understand that the author is trying to be polite. If it is spoken, and the speaker says it in a presumptuous manner, then it is really irritating.

However, **there are** people who will find it rude. They will more likely take it as a presumptuous statement.

I personally say, or write in an email, "Thank you for your consideration".
Some other alternatives include:

1. Thank you for your time.
2. I (would) appreciate your/any feedback.
3. I appreciate your consideration.

I found [a post online](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2009/08/thank-you-in-advance.html) that addresses this matter. The author gives some other alternatives:

4. Thank you for considering my request.
5. I will be grateful for any help you can provide.
6. I will appreciate your help with this situation.
7. I hope you will be able to provide the information.